# Rerendering in SF1 App

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, rerender

Is re-rendering supported in the Salesforce1 app?

Since most navigation is done via javascript it seems that links etc. using `onclick` do not work after being re-rendered, and it is standard practice for browsers to execute any injected javascript in the name of security.

That said, if I use `rerender` without a target (i.e. I want to refresh the whole page) then nothing actually gets redrawn. Is there a known-working method for dealing with this situation other than converting everything to use remote actions/objects?

Comment: You want to avoid re-rendering if at all possible in a mobile app. It's very data intensive and slow. Check out the slide deck from Wednesday's webinar titled Visualforce in Salesforce1: Optimizing your User Interface for Mobile http://www.slideshare.net/developerforce/visualforce-in-salesforce1-optimizing-your-user-interface-for-mobile. The video will be on YouTube eventually.

Comment: You seem to be asking in relation to VisualForce embedded in Salesforce1. In which nothing should really be different in regards to the VF portions. Are you still having issues here? Can you reproduce them outside of S1?

Comment: @KrisGray It was a while ago and I've not revisited since to be honest. Couldn't get it to happen in the org at the time, it seemed to be SF1 specific.

Comment: Should we close this question till you see it again and can give me a bit more info?

Comment: I'll try and recreate it later on today. The number of upvotes would suggest that quite a few people have seen this issue.

Comment: Hows that repro coming? :)

Comment: Rerendering is not the issue I had with SF1 while developing an interactive page. There are many which would hit the limit of this comment section. To resolve all these I only had to convert all thing into remote actions as a working solution. Nothing worked for me yet. Sometimes smarter use of `apex:actionfunction` + `apex:form` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can actually do is to recreate a subcomponent with updated attributes dynamically as Doug Chasman describes in his answer here

[How to set up views and navigation in Lightning?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56256/how-to-set-up-views-and-navigation-in-lightning/56266#56266)

```
    $A.createComponent(this, { parameter: component.get("v.updatedValue" }, 
        function(view) {
           var content = component.find("auraIdToBeUpdated");
           content.set("v.body", view);
    });
```

Re-creation is defacto a rerender.