# Navigation between components in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to build navigation from one component to another in a Lightning application. Following this answer [How to set up views and navigation in Lightning?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56256/how-to-set-up-views-and-navigation-in-lightning) got me working with one exception, the new page doesn't seem to be in the Salesforce1 navigation context, there is no back arrow when the second component is loaded.

Am I missing something simple? Sure feels like I am.

Answer (score 3):

This can now be accomplished via `lightning:navigation` documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation).

**Summary**

The target/ to component must implement `lightning:isUrlAddressable` interface and the source/ from component needs to include `lightning:navigation`, generate URL for a given `pageReference` (in this case to a custom component) and finally call the `navigate` method with that `pageReference`.

Here is a sample:

> Target/ To Component

**Component - myTarget.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,lightning:isUrlAddressable">
    <lightning:card iconName="standard:settings" title="Navigation Example">
        <lightning:formattedText class="slds-p-left_small" value="This is your target component."/>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

> Source/ From Component

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
    <lightning:button label="Navigate to Target Component" onclick="{!c.navigate}" />
</aura:component>
```

**Controller JS**

```
({
    navigate : function(component, event, helper) {
        var navService = component.find("navService");
        var pageReference = {
            "type": "standard__component",
            "attributes": {
                "componentName": "c__myTarget"
            }, 
            "state": {}
        };
        navService.navigate(pageReference);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Found it.. for those looking for this answer..

```
navigateToRollCall : function(component, event, helper) {
    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        evt.setParams({
            componentDef: "c:AttendanceRollCall",
            componentAttributes: {
                programId: component.get("v.program.Id")
            }
        });
    evt.fire();    
}
```

Comment: Hi @Troy, I tried it and nothing happens. The "evt" comes up as null after $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent"). May I ask where you've found documentation for this ?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working now - according to Salesforce it was never officially supported.

Comment: @Bob Buzzard. What is your other way to solve that ?

Answer (score 1):

In Summer 15, `e.force:navigateToComponent` does not work unless the target component is already loaded. I worked around this by embedding the target component in the source component in an `<aura:if isTrue="{!false}">`.

Comment: Can you give me an example how will you do that ?

Comment: For the controller Troy gave, you would have to add this to your component: `<aura:if isTrue="{!false}"><c:AttendanceRollCall/></aura:if>`

Answer (score 0):

From my reply in the thread below:

JavaScript source is not documentation, and does not indicate support. Please refer to the docs for the official API. Use of unsupported components, events, or APIs is a violation of the terms of service,  and your code may break in a release, including patch.

Answer (score -1):

The event(force:navigateToComponent) can be found in app.js which is used in Salesforce1 internally. However no docs introduce it until now(Spring '15).

Definition details,

```
{
    "$descriptor$": {
        "prefix": "markup", 
        "$namespace$": "force", 
        "name": "navigateToComponent", 
        "$qualifiedName$": "markup://force:navigateToComponent"
    }, 
    "$superDef$": {
        "$descriptor$": {
            "prefix": "markup", 
            "$namespace$": "aura", 
            "name": "applicationEvent", 
            "$qualifiedName$": "markup://aura:applicationEvent"
        }, 
        "$superDef$": null, 
        "$attributeDefs$": { }, 
        "type": "APPLICATION"
    }, 
    "$attributeDefs$": {
        "componentDef": {
            "name": "componentDef", 
            "type": "aura://String"
        }, 
        "componentAttributes": {
            "name": "componentAttributes", 
            "type": "aura://Object"
        }, 
        "forceServerDependencies": {
            "name": "forceServerDependencies", 
            "type": "aura://Boolean"
        }, 
        "resetHistory": {
            "name": "resetHistory", 
            "type": "aura://Boolean", 
            "default": false
        }, 
        "ignoreExistingAction": {
            "name": "ignoreExistingAction", 
            "type": "aura://Boolean", 
            "default": false
        }
    }, 
    "type": "APPLICATION"
}
```

Comment: JavaScript source is not documentation, and does not indicate support. Please refer to the docs for the official API. Use of unsupported components, events, or APIs is a violation of the terms of service,  and your code may break in a release, including patch.