# How to navigate from one lightning component to another lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I have tried several ways to do this and have not reached enlightenment.

I have the same problem as outlined in this question [Navigation between components in lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66513/navigation-between-components-in-lightning/67129#67129)

I was optimistic about using navigateToUrl but only .app have available urls, and .app cannot be seen in the salesforce1 mobile application. The components are not available via a direct url.

Here is what I have found:

---

This works in an app but not in mobile:

`$A.get("e.myNamespace:navigateToView").setParams({"view": "bar"}).fire();`

---

For this I cannot figure out what my recordId is for my lighning component. BTW, Also tried "componentId": "xxx" which I found in Dave Carroll's sublime manifest file:
    `$A.get("e.myNamespace:navigateToSObject").setParams({"recordId":"XXXXX2"}).fire();`

---

The following also does not work:

`$A.get("e.myNamespace:navigateToObjectHome").setParams({"scope":"myNamespace__expenseTracker__c"}).fire();`

---

This works great and will take me to the homepage. I wish it worked for lightning components:

`$A.get("e.force:navigateToURL").setParams({"url":"/_ui/core/chatter/ui/ChatterPage"}).fire();`

---

Anybody familiar with a full lightning component example that demonstrations a navigation technique that works in salesforce mobile?

Comment: The detailed solution with explanation for component navigation can be found in the link below. http://force-base.com/2016/01/04/how-to-navigate-from-one-component-to-another-in-lightning/

Answer (score 3):

Seems there is an event missing from the documentation, I went through this last week. Try this..

Component markup

```
<ui:button label="ATTENDANCE" press="{!c.navigateToRollCall}"/>
```

Controller (I am using default namespace here for my component AttendanceRollCall)

```
navigateToRollCall : function(component, event, helper) {
    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        evt.setParams({
            componentDef: "c:AttendanceRollCall",
            componentAttributes: {
                programId: component.get("v.program.Id")
            }
        });
    evt.fire();    
}
```

Comment: Can you give us some more context on how you got this to work? I can find no documentation about navigateToComponent and when I use this I get an internal error displayed that looks like this: <br />An internal server error has occurred<br/>Error ID: 1382860838-80715 (530229303)

Comment: This appears to have stopped working now. According to Salesforce it was never officially supported.  I haven't found an alternative yet.

Comment: It technically still works if you add the component you are trying to create into your markup, and surround it with an impossible condition. Like: <aura:if isTrue="{!false}"><c:AttendanceRollCall/></aura:if>

Comment: is there any working workaround guys for this?

Answer (score 3):

You could move between view states by creating and replacing components.

**Server-side Controller**

```
public class LightningController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<Account> getAccounts(){
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 10];
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<Opportunity> getOpportunities(Id AccountId){
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :AccountId];
    }

}
```

**App**

```
<aura:application controller="LightningController" >
    <aura:attribute type="Account[]" name="AccountList" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="c.doInit" />
    <aura:handler event="analysis:ATOEvent" action="{!c.ato}" />
    <aura:handler event="analysis:OTAEvent" action="{!c.ota}" />
    {!v.body}
</aura:application>
```

**App client-side controller**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper){
        var action = component.get("c.getAccounts");
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
                if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS"){
                    component.set("{!v.AccountList}",response.getReturnValue());
                    helper.generateAccountList(component);
                }
            }
        );
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    ato : function(component, event, helper){
        var action = component.get("c.getOpportunities");
        action.setParams({"AccountId" : event.getParam("AccountId")});
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
                if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS"){
                    helper.generateOpportunityList(component, response.getReturnValue());
                }
            }
        );
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    ota : function(component, event, helper){
        helper.generateAccountList(component);
    }
})
```

**App helper**

```
({
    generateAccountList : function(component) {
        $A.createComponent(
            "analysis:AccountList",
            {
                "AccountList" : component.get("{!v.AccountList}")
            },
            function(newComponent){
                component.set("v.body",newComponent);
            }
        )    
    },
    generateOpportunityList : function(component, OpportunityList){
        $A.createComponent(
            "analysis:OpportunityList",
            {
                "OpportunityList" : OpportunityList
            },
            function(newComponent){
                component.set("v.body",newComponent);
            }
        )
    }
})
```

**AccountList**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:registerEvent name="ATOEvent" type="analysis:ATOEvent" /> 
    <aura:attribute name="AccountList" type="Account[]" />
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.AccountList}" var="Account">
        <ui:outputText value="{!Account.Name}" />
        <ui:button label="go" press="c.fireato" buttonTitle="{!Account.Id}" />
        <br/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

**AccountListController**

```
({
    fireato : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = $A.get("e.analysis:ATOEvent");
        action.setParams({"AccountId" : event.getSource().get("{!v.buttonTitle}")});
        action.fire();
    }
})
```

**OpportunityList**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:registerEvent name="OTAEvent" type="analysis:OTAEvent" /> 
    <aura:attribute type="Opportunity[]" name="OpportunityList" />
    <ui:button label="Go Back" press="c.fireota" />
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.OpportunityList}" var="Opportunity" >
        <br />
        <ui:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Name}" />
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

**OpportunityListController**

```
({
    fireota : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = $A.get("e.analysis:OTAEvent");
        action.fire();
    }
})
```

**ATOEvent**

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="ATOEvent" >
    <aura:attribute name="AccountId" type="Id" />
</aura:event>
```

**OTAEvent**

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="OTAEvent" />
```

Comment: hello @martin - I tried your provided code as well but it is also throwing same 'Uncaught error in $A.run()' error when we click button to load another component. Is it working for you or just me having the issue?

Comment: @VarunC It works for me. If you can show me where the error happened, I might be able to help you trouble-shoot.

Comment: I'm getting following screen when I load the Lightning Sample App I created using the code above - [link](http://screencast.com/t/VBMqYdc7) and then when I click `Go` button I get following error - [error link](http://screencast.com/t/1FSNe006nWU)

Comment: Thanks to your comments @martin ... I'm able to find the issue. Actually I missed removing the namespace `analysis` from Events created in the code, and fixing that made the code working fine. Thanks a bunch for this workaround :-) ...

Comment: @waveforms I think you should mark this post as an accepted answer, since the provided code works just fine after replacing the `analysis`  namespace with `c` or your `chosen namespace` of the org and it solves the navigation of two lightning components as needed.

Comment: hello @martin, can you confirm here if the navigation will work only for APPLICATION and not for COMPONENT using the code? I'm trying to build a Component with Component to Component navigation, but received same error as before, and then I noticed that you have used APPLICATION (aura:aplication) instead of (aura:component to start with.

Comment: @VarunC In my org, I was able to get this to work by putting everything from the application into a new component/controller/helper (only changing aura:application to aura:component), and putting that component inside an application: `<aura:application  ><analysis:ContainerComponent /></aura:application>`.

Comment: Strange, when I ported the same code to Component and used component inside an application it didn't worked. I'll recheck my code, may be I missed something, thanks for the confirmation :-)

Answer (score 3):

Lightning component navigation has been re-defined in Winter'17 and we now have a native event to navigate through components.

Suppose you have a component named as MyComponent2.cmp and you want to navigate to this component from one of your existing components, then you can do it like this

```
NavigatetoC2 : function(component, event, helper) {
        var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        evt.setParams({
                componentDef : "c:MyComponent2",
                componentAttributes: {

                }
        });
        evt.fire();
}
```

The detailed solution for the same can be found in my latest post below

[Lightning-component-Navigation-Winter'17](https://force-base.com/2016/11/06/lightning-components-navigation-re-defined-in-winter17-woooo-hooooo/)

Comment: Hi Akhil, it's nice to have this functionality implemented but I am not able to have this its not responding any event on press of button. I am using Lighting out. Can u plz tell me is this functionality is available or not with lightning out.

Answer (score 2):

The way to "navigate" from one component to another is to create and replace components within a container component. The container component can then be published to the Salesforce1 mobile app in a Lightning App created using the Lightning App Builder, or published to the web in a Lightning App created using the Developer Console.

It's a bit confusing (to me) because the term Lightning App is used twice to describe two different things. The Lightning App Builder "Lightning App" is mobile-only, and only available in the Salesforce1 mobile app. The Developer Console "Lightning App" is web-only, and available to anyone with a web browser and a Salesforce account, to which an admin has granted access to your app.

As noted on the Salesforce Developers Blog:

"What might not be obvious ... is that Salesforce1 is essentially what is known as a Single Page App or SPA." "In an SPA, page content is manipulated behind the scenes using client-side JavaScript, creating the appearance of separate pages."

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/04/creating-lightning-components-1.html

Answer (score 0):

This can now be accomplished via `lightning:navigation` documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation).

**Summary**

The target/ to component must implement `lightning:isUrlAddressable` interface and the source/ from component needs to include `lightning:navigation`, generate URL for a given `pageReference` (in this case to a custom component) and finally call the `navigate` method with that `pageReference`.

Here is a sample:

> Target/ To Component

**Component - myTarget.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,lightning:isUrlAddressable">
    <lightning:card iconName="standard:settings" title="Navigation Example">
        <lightning:formattedText class="slds-p-left_small" value="This is your target component."/>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

> Source/ From Component

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
    <lightning:button label="Navigate to Target Component" onclick="{!c.navigate}" />
</aura:component>
```

**Controller JS**

```
({
    navigate : function(component, event, helper) {
        var navService = component.find("navService");
        var pageReference = {
            "type": "standard__component",
            "attributes": {
                "componentName": "c__myTarget"
            }, 
            "state": {}
        };
        navService.navigate(pageReference);
    }
})
```