# Visualforce Wizard in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

Has anyone used the Visualforce Wizard cookbook recipe in Salesforce1?

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/creating-a-wizard-with-visualforce-pages

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the best option would be to use something like the Bootstrap Wizard instead. http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this will work as the example as salesforce1 is less about pages and more about components.  Note the example redirects the user to separate visualforce pages for each step.   You navigate lightning components per this question: [How to navigate from one lightning component to another lightning component?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66954/how-to-navigate-from-one-lightning-component-to-another-lightning-component)

If each component is independent as per the original example then you should be able to construct a similar experience.