# How to navigate from one component to another with value

Tags: visualforce, community, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

**Component1**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
    <aura:attribute name="accountid" type="String" />
    <ui:inputNumber aura:id="test1" label="Name" />
    <ui:button label="Navigate" press="{!c.Naviagte}" />
</aura:component>
({
    Add: function(component, event, helper) {
        var get_name = component.find("testt1").get("v.value");
        var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        evt.setParams({
            componentDef: "c:Component2",
            componentAttributes: {
                accountid: get_name
            }
        });
        evt.fire();
    }
})
```

**Component2**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
      Hello
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    var ResultValue = event.getParam("accountid");
    // it navigate fine but i am not able to get pass attribute value here
}
```

Comment: Hi pankaj, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Please don't just do a "code dump" on us. Instead, tell us where you're stuck and what you're having trouble with, including what you've tried that didn't work. Once you do, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful.

Comment: thanks sir,but i try to get passed attribute value from component one in component2 in many way i am not able to get it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/66954/20830](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66954/how-to-navigate-from-one-lightning-component-to-another-lightning-component)

Comment: `e.force:navigateToComponent` is an undocument event which is not officially supported by Salesforce.Use `$A.createComponent` to create components as given in the above link's answer

Comment: thanks praveen sir, i try your given link but still my problem  not solved

Comment: post the code you tried by editing the question i'll help you out.