# Lightning - Standalone app - Events

Tags: lightning-aura-components, event

I have a component listing all my users and for each user there is a edit button which will trigger an application event to set the content (as seen [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56256/how-to-set-up-views-and-navigation-in-lightning)) of the userItem to allow the input by the user.

As I understand it,  my event is on a application level, each component handling this event will respond if the event is fired. As I want to edit a user at a time on my list, my approach isn't good.

So how do I do to fire an event for a single component which is displayed multiple times but for different instances ?

Thank you

*Update*
I realize I have to use component events, as they do not interfere with others components. Can someone show me an example for my context ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering, you just have to set body of the item you want to change, see below for an example

Provided you have a button which will trigger the function navToUserEdit

```
navToUserEdit : function(component, event) {
    var destination = "markup://c:userEdit";
    $A.componentService.newComponentAsync(this, function(item) {
        var content = component.find("content");
        content.set("v.body", item);
    }, {
        componentDef: destination,
        attributes: {
            values: {
                userFromEvent: "{!v.user}"
            }
        }
    }, component);
},
```

With the newComponentAsync, I can send the attribute user to the userEdit component, and now I can manage its behaviour for editing purposes.

Note that the destination is hardcoded, it's not an event either, but it does the trick.

Also, if you're on the one/one.app, you don't have to do that, just use the navigateToComponent featured in Salesforce1, as seen [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66513/navigation-between-components-in-lightning)