# Lightning App redirect from 1 component to another component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, lightning-connect

In my Lightning Project i have 2 different components (Login Component,Home Component). What i want is when the user click the login button. The user will redirect to the home component.

Comment: Check this out: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56256/how-to-set-up-views-and-navigation-in-lightning And : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66513/navigation-between-components-in-lightning?lq=1

Comment: Did you apply link of scenarios to your code ?.. Will you give a simple complete working code for that ? regards

Comment: check this perfect example https://force-base.com/2016/01/04/how-to-navigate-from-one-component-to-another-in-lightning/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In Login Component component**

```
<ui:button label="Navigate to foo" press="{!c.navigateToHome}"/>
```

**In Login controller**

```
navigateToHome : function(component, event, helper) {
var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
    evt.setParams({
        componentDef: "c:YourHomeComponent",
        componentAttributes: {
            myAttribute: component.get("v.someAttribute")
        }
    });
    evt.fire();    
}
```