# Is $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent") available and documented in Winter'16?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, navigation

I found the usage of `$A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent")` described in this answer here [How to set up views and navigation in Lightning?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56256/how-to-set-up-views-and-navigation-in-lightning/67130#67130)

But reviewing the documentation, there is only

- force:navigateToList
- force:navigateToObjectHome
- force:navigateToRelatedList
- force:navigateToSObjectHome
- force:navigateToURL

Is this force:navigateToComponent aviailable, supported and documented now? (in Winter'16)

Comment: It's not documented till now. But hopefully we'll be able to use properly documented equivalent of $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent") by Winter 17. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/133189/29317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

force:navigateToComponent is now available in Beta in Winter '17 and is documented here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToComponent.htm

Answer (score 3):

In this answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/89570/7515 @Skip Sauls mentioned that we can not rely on functionality available in JS API if it's not described in Docs. 
And I believe the latest documentation is deployed to every org (https://instance.salesforce.com/auradocs#reference)

Hope this event will be supported in future releases.

Comment: Thanks @steals - So as a conclusion `force:navigateToComponent` is not in the docs (as of today) and therefore not usable, right? And the answer http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56256/how-to-set-up-views-and-navigation-in-lightning/67130#67130 is simply wrong yet?

Comment: @UweHeim In case, if you haven't seen this already http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/133189/29317