# Pagescroll not working in Pages which are navigated to a lightning component in Salesforce1 app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, app-builder

I am facing an issue with the normal pagescroll in the lightning component in Summer'16.

The scroll is not working in pages which are navigated to a lightning component in the Salesforce 1 app.

Pagescroll is working for a page developed using app builder.
But as per Salesforce `https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000017yktQAA` it's said that it has been fixed. But still, i am facing the issue.

Here's the example code

**First Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"> 
  <!-- Optional coponent attributes here -->
  <!-- Optional HTML markup -->
  <div class="container">
    <button onclick="{!c.gotoCompTwo}" class="slds-button"> Go to Component 2 
    </button>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

**First component's Controller**

```
gotoProductForecast : function(component, event) {

        var navigateEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");

        navigateEvent.setParams({
            componentDef: "c:Component2",
            componentAttributes: {
                //Set attributes if any
            }
        });
        navigateEvent.fire();
}
```

**Second component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

  <!-- Optional coponent attributes here -->

  <!-- Optional HTML markup -->

  <div class="container">
  //Required contents (Say, the content exceeds more than the vertical screen size)
  <!-- Other components -->
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

The native pagescroll works in the 1st component.

But after clicking the button, when it navigates to the second component, the pagescroll doesn't work even if the content exceeds the screen size. (I am not even able to swipe the page down to refresh the page!)

It would be very helpful if someone could could provide any insights on this.

Comment: Are you trying it in the browser or using the latest Salesforce1 app?

Comment: I've tried in the Chrome web browser(Version 50.0.2661.102 (64-bit)) simulator and also in iPad and iPhone (Salesforce1 app).. The page does not scroll (the native scroll).

Comment: Could you provide with more denials with your issue?

Comment: Hi @JFParadis , I've a main component (developed using App Builder) and from there on button click I'm navigating to another component using force:navigateToComponent. The scroll is working fine on the page developed using App Builder. But scroll is not working on the page which is  navigated to from the main component. Earlier, this was working just fine. Can you please suggest any workaround for this scenario?

Comment: Can you give me repro steps (a small sytnetic app)? I can look into this right-away.

Comment: Hi @JFParadis, 1-->Create a lightning component with a button on it which is built using app builder.  
2--> On button click, using  force:navigateToComponent, it's navigated to another already created component.
The scroll does not work in the navigated page (In browser as well as in device).

Comment: Hi @JFParadis Can you please tell me if you could reproduce the same issue? If so, can you please tell me if there are any workarounds for the same?

Comment: Hi @JFParadis Any updates on this?

Comment: No update at the moment. @Trevor-Bliss could you take a look.

Comment: @AravindAjith do you have any example code you can add to your question? How are you creating/firing your navigateToComponent event? What does the component you're navigating to look like? I'm not able to reproduce the issue locally.

Comment: Hi @Trevor Thank you for looking into it. I've updated the question with example code. 
The second component is used to display records of an object which is returned from the apex controller. So when there are more records, the content exceeds the viewable vertical screen size. 
After navigating to the second component, it's like the page is frozen/stuck! (I am not even able to swipe down the page to refresh.)

Comment: Hi @Trevor Any updates on this?

Comment: @Trevor Could you please tell me if there are any updates regarding this? The page scroll is still stuck.

Comment: @Trevor Hi, any updates??

Comment: Hi @JFParadis Could you please tell me if you've got any updates regarding this?

Comment: @AravindAjit, I will get back to you today.

Answer (score 7):

An equivalent to `force:navigateToComponent` will be released GA as a public API, it's under the category of "Global Components" that is scheduled for this coming release "Winter 17":

http://web-auth.salesforce.com/campaigns/lightning/index.jsp#Roadmap

We appear to be on track to release "Global Components" around 25 lightning components, interfaces, and events, and `lightning:navigateToComponent` will be one of them. All of these are SLDS enabled, which is the main goal.

Our roll-out of the Winter releases usually begins in August and goes in stages all the way thought September. We don't have the public blog post yet, but this is a link to last year's Winter 16:

https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2015/08/salesforce-winter-16-coming-soon.html

The dates will most likely be similar. Please understand that I am composing from various sources, and that you should wait for the formal announcements before making a final decision (Safe Harbor rules). I understand your issues, and I wished I had a better answer, but I hope that this can still help you strategize your development process.

Comment: Hi @JFParadis The pagescroll still doesn't work in pages which are navigated from the first component. I can see `force:navigateToComponent` is currently in Beta as per the doc. Is it because of that? Are there any updates regarding this?

Comment: Hi @JFParadis, Any updates? Also can you please check [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151463/unable-to-add-custom-scroll-due-to-component-namespace-encapsulation-when-lock?noredirect=1#comment222097_151463) out?

Comment: This is a huge issue!! Without being able to navigatetoComponent the pull to refresh resets to initial component state.  Workaround involves creating components dynamically which does not suite complex applications.  Imagine a user who has navigated X components deeps which does a pull to refresh only to be reset to initial state.

Answer (score 1):

As of today the method `$A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent")` is not yet available in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_events.htm). It could be leading to wrong rendering of pages or maybe it has some other unexpected behaviors...

A possible workaround, depending on your use-case is to [dynamically create](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm) the component, instead of navigating to it.

Comment: Hi @FernandoGavinho Thanks for the suggestion. We would also like to have navigation option. By creating components dynamically, default back button for navigating back to the component (in SF1) would be lost, right? 
 We're also having multiple level navigation which would make it very complex if we create components dynamically.

Answer (score -2):

The **force:navigateToComponent** is replaced by **lightning:navigation** in Summer '18 release. Here is how you would implement it:

The first component must include **lightning:navigation** component with a unique aura:id in the markup. It doesn't have any UI attached to it, so it's safe to add it anywhere in the component.

> First Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"> 
  <!-- Optional coponent attributes here -->
  <!-- Optional HTML markup -->
  <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
  <div class="container">
    <button onclick="{!c.gotoCompTwo}" class="slds-button"> Go to Component 2 
    </button>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

In the controller you need to build the pageReference JavaScript object which will construct the URL for the destination Lightning component. Here is how you build it.

> First Component's Controller

```
gotoCompTwo : function(component, event) {

    var nav = component.find("navService");
    var pageReference = {
        "type": "standard__component",
        "attributes": {
            "componentName": "c__Component2"
        }, 
        "state": {
            //Other optional attributes
            //e.g. "recordId" :  sampleRecordId
        }
    };  
    nav.navigate(pageReference);
}
```

The second component which is where you want to navigate to must implement **lightning:isUrlAddressable** interface.

> Second Component

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable" >

    <!-- Optional coponent attributes here -->
    <!-- Optional HTML markup -->

</aura:component>
```

Comment: Any suggestions for improving the answer?