# How to navigate from one lightning component to another Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am new to salesforce Lightning component and I meet a problem about how to navigate from one lightning component to another Lightning component,I want to know what is the best practise for it?

Now I just build a desktop app, in one component named **studys** I have a button and when I click the button I want to show the **studyDetail** component, and the **studys** component is not on the page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need three components in total, lets say my third component  studysMainCmp and is as below.

```
<aura:component access="global" implements="force:appHostable">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:handler event="c:navigateToCmp" action="{!c.NavigateComponent}" />

    <div>
        {!v.body}
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    $A.createComponent("c:studys", {

    }, function(newCmp) {
        if (component.isValid()) {
            component.set("v.body", newCmp);
        }
    });
},

NavigateComponent : function(component, event, helper) {
if(event.getParam("navigate") == "true")
{
    $A.createComponent("c:studyDetail", {

        }, function(newCmp) {
            if (component.isValid()) {
                component.set("v.body", newCmp);
            }
        });
}
}
```

In your **study** component the button action should fire an event, the button function will be as below

```
buttonFunction : function(component, event) {
    var event = $A.get("e.c:navigateToCmp");
    event.setParams({
        "navigate" : "true"
    });
    event.fire();
},
```

Lightning event named navigateToCmp will be as below:

```
<aura:event access="global" type="APPLICATION" description="Event template" >
    <aura:attribute name="navigate" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
</aura:event>
```

Please follow the blog https://force-base.com/2016/01/04/how-to-navigate-from-one-component-to-another-in-lightning/

It worked for me, hope it helps for you.

Answer (score 2):

The event(force:navigateToComponent) can be found in app.js which is used here. However no docs introduce it until now(Spring '15).

On component

```
<button onclick="{!c.newComponent}" > YOUR BUTTON </button>
```

In controller

```
newComponent : function(component) {
var newEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        newEvent.setParams({
            componentDef: "newComponent",
            componentAttributes: {
                //Set you attributes here if required.
            }
        });
        newEvent.fire();
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I already try it before, it doesn't work , maybe 'e.force:navigateToComponent' is not avalible now. Are you sure You can work with this??

Comment: Yes.We are using this. Can you post your code?

Comment: @ming This might help you http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/133189/29317 (Also, e.force:navigateToComponent currently works for me too.)