# Critical Update Bug? "Add a Namespace Prefix to Query Parameters and pageReference.state Properties"

Tags: lightning, url, critical-update

This critical update is breaking several of my lightning components that use the URL to receive parameters. It is stripping out parameters, however none of my fields or parameters are part of a managed package. They aren't "query parameters". Not sure why anything related to pageReferences would even affect my lightning components since I'm pretty certain the lightning framework doesn't care about "pageReference.state" at all.

This feels like a bug to me. If I tell that to salesforce support (which I'm about to do anyway) they are going to tell me that I don't have developer support. AKA, probably useless as is usually the case.

Here is an example of the URL that gets produced when I have the critical update off:
https://hs--deviv.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/RecordCreatePage?Object=Account&RecTypeId=01241000000VE0hAAG&ReturnRecId=0013C000009sJ9NQAU&Name=Test2018-09-28&ParentId=0013C000009sJ9NQAU&Account_Type__c=Franchise&BillingCity=Austin&BillingCountryCode=US&BillingPostalCode=78701&BillingStateCode=TX&BillingStreet=123%20Some%20Street2018-09-28&ShippingCity=Austin&ShippingCountryCode=US&ShippingPostalCode=78701&ShippingStateCode=TX&ShippingStreet=123%20Some%20Street2018-09-28&POS_Type__c=a0F3C0000007OyoUAE&Concept__c=a033C000001LHOGQA4&OwnerId=00541000000k4fPAAQ&Customer_Success_Manager__c=null&Sales_Rep__c=null

Here is clicking the exact same link with the update on:
https://hs--deviv.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/RecordCreatePage?Account_Type__c=Franchise&POS_Type__c=a0F3C0000007OyoUAE&Concept__c=a033C000001LHOGQA4&Sales_Rep__c=null

So, a whole bunch of seemingly random parameters just get deleted upon navigation. Doesn't seem like that's something the update is supposed to do. Any thoughts? Anybody else having this issue?

Just realized - this isn't a URL button like I thought. It's housed in a lightning component on the lightning record page.

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="record" type="Account"/>

<force:recordData aura:id="accountLoader"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  layoutType="FULL"     
                  targetRecord="{!v.record}"                        
                  targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"    
                  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                  />    

<div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">      
    <div class="slds-text-heading_small">
        Data Coordinator Panel
    </div>    

    <br/>
     <ui:button label="Create Store" press="{!c.gotoURL}" />
</div>
```

Controller:

```
({
gotoURL : function(component, event, helper) {
    var a = component.get('v.record');    
    function fullEncode(str){
            // Put some special URL encoding in here since apostrophes explode the whole world
       return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(new RegExp('\'', 'g') , 'xxapostrophexx');
    }


    var urlString = '/one/one.app#/n/RecordCreatePage?Object=Account&RecTypeId=01241000000VE0hAAG';
        urlString += '&ReturnRecId=' + fullEncode(a.fields.Id.value);
        urlString += '&Name=' + fullEncode(a.fields.Name.value);
        urlString += '&ParentId=' + fullEncode(a.fields.Id.value);
        urlString += '&Account_Type__c=' + fullEncode(a.fields.Account_Type__c.value);
        urlString += '&BillingCity=' + fullEncode(a.fields.BillingCity.value);
        urlString += '&BillingCountryCode=' + fullEncode(a.fields.BillingCountryCode.value);
        urlString += '&BillingPostalCode=' + fullEncode(a.fields.BillingPostalCode.value);
        urlString += '&BillingStateCode=' + fullEncode(a.fields.BillingStateCode.value);
        urlString += '&BillingStreet=' + fullEncode(a.fields.BillingStreet.value);
        urlString += '&ShippingCity=' + fullEncode(a.fields.ShippingCity.value);
        urlString += '&ShippingCountryCode=' + fullEncode(a.fields.ShippingCountryCode.value);
        urlString += '&ShippingPostalCode=' + fullEncode(a.fields.ShippingPostalCode.value);
        urlString += '&ShippingStateCode=' + fullEncode(a.fields.ShippingStateCode.value);
        urlString += '&ShippingStreet=' + fullEncode(a.fields.ShippingStreet.value);
        urlString += '&POS_Type__c=' + fullEncode(a.fields.POS_Type__c.value);
        urlString += '&Concept__c='+ fullEncode(a.fields.Concept__c.value);
        urlString += '&OwnerId=' + fullEncode(a.fields.OwnerId.value);
        urlString += '&Customer_Success_Manager__c=' + fullEncode(a.fields.Customer_Success_Manager__c.value);
        urlString += '&Sales_Rep__c=' + fullEncode(a.fields.Sales_Rep__c.value);

    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url": urlString
    })
    urlEvent.fire();
}
```

})

Comment: can you post the relevant code that is generating that url?

Comment: fwiw, it stripped everything except parameters ending in `__c`, total hack, but if you added __c to the rest of your parameter names seems like it might just avoid whatever is causing the other parameters to get stripped ...

Comment: I would have to prefix them with something as well so I know to strip the prefix and "__c" suffix when I actually process them... but that's a great idea! This is already pretty much a hack to get around them taking away my javascript buttons I used to pre-populate records and land on the edit screen without saving so might as well throw another hack on as well!

Comment: Basically it's happy as long as I put 2 underscores in there. So it works if do either
"z__Object" or "Object__x".

Further confirms for me that this is a bug. Now just to get support to listen to my non-premium support having self and actually flag this as a bug.

Comment: double underscores are one way of identifying a managed package, i.e. `Zuora__Subscription__c`, could see it just being a poor implementation of stripping the parameters that aren't managed packages (i.e. `[^_]*__.*` is managed package, but they're doing `.*__.*`)

Comment: Yep. Plus based on the actual content of the critical update it's only supposed to apply to "Query parameters" and "pageReference.State". Guess that also means e.force:navigateToURL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the critical update mentions query parameters it's referring the the values in the URL after the `?`, so `BillingCity=`, `Sales_Rep__c=`, etc. The terminology is a bit inconsistent, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39266970/84130) for an extended discussion on the matter. So if anything the bug in this case is that it's not stripping all your url parameters.

My guess is that this is intended to prevent components in a different name space from reading the content of URL parameters from components in different spaces. While it appears that merely including a double underscore in the parameter name works for you now, it's likely that will get fixed in the future and everything will get stripped. In general the "default" namespace is indicated by `c__`, so I expect the correct way to do this -- **if** you're manually building the url -- is to prefix each of you're parameters with `c__` and they won't get stripped.

That said, in general you'd want to try and let Salesforce handle figuring out the URL structure for you, so if they change the URL structure or behavior in the future you're component continues to work. In comparison in visualforce the "more" official way to nagivate to an account would be using the `URLFOR` method, i.e. `<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, account.id)}"/>` as opposed to building the link yourself `<apex:outputLink value="\{!account.Id}"/>`.

I'm not much of an expert in lighting, but based on little digging I think you want to use `lighting:navigation` to accomplish this and pass through the attributes in PageReference.state as outlined in this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/228400/594)

> This can now be accomplished via `lightning:navigation` documented
>   [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation).
>
> **Summary**
>
> The target/ to component must implement `lightning:isUrlAddressable`
>   interface and the source/ from component needs to include
>   `lightning:navigation`, generate URL for a given `pageReference` (in
>   this case to a custom component) and finally call the `navigate`
>   method with that `pageReference`.
>
> Here is a sample:
>
> > Target/ To Component
>
> **Component - myTarget.cmp**
>
> ```
> <aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,lightning:isUrlAddressable">
>     <lightning:card iconName="standard:settings" title="Navigation Example">
>         <lightning:formattedText class="slds-p-left_small" value="This is your target component."/>
>     </lightning:card>
> </aura:component>
> ```
>
> > Source/ From Component
>
> **Component**
>
> ```
> <aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
>     <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
>     <lightning:button label="Navigate to Target Component" onclick="{!c.navigate}" />
> </aura:component>
> ```
>
> **Controller JS**
>
> ```
> ({
>     navigate : function(component, event, helper) {
>         var navService = component.find("navService");
>         var pageReference = {
>             "type": "standard__component",
>             "attributes": {
>                 "componentName": "c__myTarget"
>             }, 
>             "state": {}
>         };
>         navService.navigate(pageReference);
>     }
> })
> ```

Comment: Great answer Ralph. I currently have an outstanding case with SF and from what little I've heard back from them it sounds like the current behavior was not the intention. I'll update this again with more details and hopefully a known issue link for people to flag if this is affecting them as well.

Comment: meaning that it shouldn't have stripped your parameters? or it should have stripped all of them?

Comment: Gave the thead you highlighted another read through and I think it confirms the way I was grabbing and processing the URL was never supported, so using lightning:navigation and setting attributes looks like what I'm going to have to change to. The challenge here is I'm passing an unknown number of dynamic fields for a dynamic object. I'm planning to handle this by just passing all of my key value pairs in a string attribute instead of the URL which will allow me to keep my logic all more or less the same.