# How to go from one lightning page to another lightning page through a click?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

How can I redirect from one Lightning page to another lightning page through a click on a component link? I can only find answers for navigating from one lightning component to another lightning component.

Comment: By "Lightning Page" do you mean an app builder page?

Comment: Yes. Or go from component link to an App Builder Page.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `force:navigateToURL` event  is used to navigate to a URL.

Use a relative url to stay in your current app and go to a different page.

```
goToNewPage: function(component, event, helper) {

    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
        "url": "/newPage"
    });

    urlEvent.fire();
}
```

Use an absolute URL to open an external website in a new browser tab.

```
goToExternalSite: function(component, event, helper) {

    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
        "url": "http:www.google.com"
    });

    urlEvent.fire();
}
```

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm

Answer (score 3):

You don't go from page to page.. you load components in and out of the current application context.

component.set("v.body",newComponent);

here is a good discussion.. [How to set up views and navigation in Lightning?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56256/how-to-set-up-views-and-navigation-in-lightning)