# Is $A.componentService.newComponentAsync available in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, navigation

I found @DougChasman using

```
$A.componentService.newComponentAsync
```

in his example here [How to set up views and navigation in Lightning?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56256/how-to-set-up-views-and-navigation-in-lightning/56266#56266)

However in the docs I see only `$A.newCmpAsync` and marked **DEPRECATED**.

Is that example referenced above no longer working in it's exact form?

Only in case it's no longer working: since there are only rare examples of that kind, wouldn't it be worth for us as community to update it to be compatible with the current release and today's best practices?

Comment: I've updated my post above to use the latest and greatest (did not exist when I wrote it)

Comment: Thanks @DougChasman, your post is one of the most important about Lightning navigation and since it differs a lot from Visualforce it will help us with that transition.

Answer (score 5):

The latest reference docs at `[your-domain]/auradocs/reference.app` should now show `$A.createComponent` as the standard for Winter '16. You can also look at the LC Dev Guide topic on [Dynamically Creating Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm) for an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. I'll point that link also a comment to the OP referenced above